# how can i choose a file randomly from a folder without reading all of the files to memory

Tags: python, file

I have a folder with a very large number of files. I want to choose a random file iteratively.

Currently, I use `glob.glob()` to get all of the possible files and then I use `random.sample()` to get some of the files randomly at each iteration. Sometimes my computer shows " out of memory " because of this.

*Is there some way to just randomly select a file out of the folder without looking for all of the files first?*

code:

`mfcc_files_paths = random.sample(glob.glob(self.path_to_paths + "\\mfcc\\*.mfcc.npy"), int(n_samples))`

console:
  File "blah blah blah.py", line 109, in get_random_mfcc_txt_pairs
    mfcc_files_paths = random.sample(glob.glob(self.path_to_paths + "\mfcc\*.mfcc.npy"), int(n_samples))
  File "C:\Users\dan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\glob.py", line 20, in glob
    return list(iglob(pathname, recursive=recursive))
MemoryError

Comment: We'll be able to help much more effectively if you [edit] and include your code that leads to an OoM. See [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

If you really cannot help keeping all those files in a single directory, you could:

- count how many files there are using `iglob` or `os.scandir`
- choose a random number in the range
- iterate until this number

for example:

```
import glob,random

path = "/path/to/dir/*"

nb_files = sum(1 for _ in glob.iglob(path))
index = random.randrange(0,nb_files)
g = glob.iglob(path)
for _ in range(index):
    file = next(g)
```

this scans the directory possibly twice but that's a memory vs disk access tradeoff.

In the future, you may want to store your files in separate directories (the easiest is to store files starting with "A" in a directory called "A" and so on, maybe use several directory levels), then picking a file at random is much easier: first pick the directory & repeat until you've reached the "files" level. More calls to `random.randint` but much faster disk access.

Comment: Re nested directories: if the directories are of different sizes, then this method will be biased unless you weight by size, which still requires a directory scan for each subdirectory.

Comment: That is true so you cannot avoid scanning all files

Answer (score 1):

`glob` module also has a `iglob` function that returns an iterator of all the files so it doesn't take up all the memory, but you can't use `random.sample()` with iterator (because it doesn't know the total number). So if you only what a single file, maybe just use a random number:

```
for file in glob.iglob(path):
    if random.random() < 0.1:   # you can pick any number here
         break
```

then `file` will be the "randomly selected" file. 
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Note that although the file will technically be randomly selected, it's not going to be a uniform sample. Specifically, files near the beginning of the iterator will have a significantly higher likelihood of being selected than files near the end

Comment: @Hamms Yeah, I'm sure there's better way of sampling then just picking a random number each time. Maybe we should penalize it with the `index` of where they appear?